# readall not defined in julia lang

Tags: css, julia

I'm setting up a custom stylesheet in IJulia.

```
file = open("style.css") # A .css file in the same folder as this notebook file
style = readall(file) # Read the file
HTML("$style") # Output as HTML
```

Error:

```
UndefVarError: readall not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[6]:3
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you are asking how to read an entire file to a `String`. Here is how:

```
style = open("style.css") do f
   read(f, String)
end
```

Note that this assumes that `style.css` is UTF-8 encoded (with plain ASCII encoding this will work too)